# Unable to use Official nVidia Drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, nvidia-geforce

I've been trying to install a working driver for the EVGA GForce GTX 1050 ti.

I've tried the instructions from nvidia.com as well as tech support.

I've tried going into settings-software and updates-additional drivers and get the following:

[image: drivers available, but i can only use the x server one]

I select one of the newest drivers (the one above the x server one) and hit apply changes.

Once the changes are applied, the orange selector dot pops right back to the x server option, which you can see in the link/pic above.

How do I stop this? I need the most out of my graphics card for using blender and CURA.

Answer (score 2):

From 4.4 on, ubuntu kernels will not load unsigned kernel modules if secure boot is turned on.

Comment: secure boot is a setting on the BIOS or UEFI right?

Comment: yes in the UEFI settings

Comment: Can you expand on this answer ? Either explain how to sign modules https://computerlinguist.org/make-dkms-sign-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot-on-ubuntu-1604.html (probably best, secure boot is not going away any time soon) or explain how to disable secure boot.

Comment: There is even a script to sign kernel modules - https://gist.github.com/Garoe/74a0040f50ae7987885a0bebe5eda1aa

Comment: turned secure boot off. also got rid of the boot supervisor password just in case. still, if i try to select the proprietary driver for the amd cpu and one of the nvidia drivers and hit apply changes, the orange bubbles always pop back to the xorg driver and "do not use this device" respectively.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen -- another option is to install a non-ubuntu kernel.

Comment: @ravery - What is the point of that advice , an non-ubuntu kernel ? That is evern harder than signing a kernel module

Comment: @bodhi.zazen --it is actually easier than signing a module. but anyway, should I delete because this isn't his issue?